# How to navigate between divs On Success in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on single page application, I have been navigating between divs, its simple but i wanted to do it with ajax....

> I wanted to do something like When "success" function called then it should send/scroll user view to another div..... I already tried the
>   .animate but failed....

Any kind of help or reference will be appreciated

```
<div id="SecondInfo"></div>
        <script>
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
                $.ajax({        
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
                   dataType: "JSon",
                   data: { "FirstName": FirstName},
                   success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
                       $("#SecondInfo").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
                   },
                   error: console.log("it did not work"),
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `scrollTop()` inside `animate()` and set the offset from element what you want to focused, here part of code .

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#second').offset().top}, 200, function() {
//next code
    });
```

Demo JsFIddle
[Scroll animate](http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/tL3kxrb1/2/)

Comment: please edit answer...so i can accept it..... please replace first with "html,body" if you agree

Answer (score 1):

Try `.focus()`

```
<script>
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
                $.ajax({        
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
                dataType: "JSon",
                data: { "FirstName": FirstName},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#SecondInfo").focus();
                },
                error: console.log("it did not work"),
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, +1 for answer .focus not working for me...any idea what are the possible causes ???

Answer (score 1):

Ok let me assume you have 4 `divs` and each with single `input` element as below and the first one will have the `active` class and remaining will be hidden:

```
<div id="parentStep">
    <div id="div1" class="steps active">
         <input type="text" id="firstName"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="steps">
         <input type="text" id="lastName"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="steps">
         <input type="text" id="contacNum"/>
    </div>
    <div id="div4" class="steps">
         <input type="text" id="addressDetail"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in your `ajax` on `success` just try to find the `div`  with active class and `hide` it and `show` `div` which is next to it as below:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
      var activeDiv=$("#parentStep").find('.steps .active');//get the active div
      var dataToSend=activeDiv.find('input').val();//get the input value of active div
      $.ajax({        
               type: "POST",
               url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Home")',
               dataType: "JSon",
               data: { "Data": dataToSend},
               success: function (data) {
                     activeDiv.fadeOut("slow").removeClass('active');//remove active from current step
                     activeDiv.next().fadeIn('fast').addClass('active');//get the next div visible and add active class
               },
               error: function(data){
                 console.log("it did not work"),
               }
       });
});
```

Comment: it's cool, it's use hide and show, but i think this is  not scrolled.

Comment: @viyancs It uses `hide` and `show` that's why there is no scroll required!! Hope you got my point!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i appreciate the effort, this answer does not suit my view code.... although its brilliant solution to the case... cheers

Comment: Not a prob @SuhailMumtazAwan. Happy Coding.. :)